# PHP Date Formatting with IntlDateFormatter

Tags: php, date, internationalization

I noticed, that when formatting a date with PHP's [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) the result can be very different depending on the language. Example:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("en_GB",
                        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                        "Europe/Vienna");

$date = $formatter->format(0);
```

In this example `$date` will be `31/12/1969` but if I use de_DE as a locale `$date` is `31.12.69`. The different is bigger when using `IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM`:

- German: `31.12.1969`
- English: `31 Dec 1969`

Is there a way to get more similar results without specifying the format?

Comment: I am not sure to follow you. What is the behavior that you were expecting ?

Comment: You mean "is there a way to get all the nations in the world to use the same date format"? That's a political question, not a coding question

Comment: I would like to have similar formats. Who defines, that for me as German 31.12.69 is a short date format and 31.12.1969 is a medium format? I would like to get 31.12.1969 as the german format and 31/12/1969 as the british format with the same formatter format

Comment: Your thinking of "similar" could be different from others think, and from what ICU had decided. You may join ICU to try to change formats, but I do not think you succeed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ICU docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) say:

> 1. SHORT is numeric, such as 12/13/52 or 3:30pm
> 2. MEDIUM is longer, such as Jan. 12, 1952
> 3. LONG is longer, such as January 12, 1952 or 3:30:32pm
> 4. FULL is completely specified, such as Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD or 3:30:42pm PST

So probably you're right with rising questions like:  "who defines those short/medium formats, and who decide about how it looks like?".

All decision like that are confirmed by CLDR, and their process [is described as](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/process):

> Once data for a country and language has been received, the data from
>   the different sources will be compared to show agreements and
>   differences. Initial data contributions are normally marked as draft;
>   this may be changed once the data is vetted.
>
> Note that there are two types of data in the repository:
>
> - Common Data: The contents is decided upon by the CLDR Technical Committee, following its procedures and this process.
> - Comparison data: The contributor can be an individual or an organization. Data is normally gathered by calling public APIs, to
>     ensure that the data matches what is actually in use. The data is only
>     for comparison, and will not be changed except where necessary to
>     update the data to match the external source. The only requirement is
>     that all changed data be versioned, and the Version Numbering Scheme
>     be used.
>
> Contributors are encouraged to use local language and country
>   contacts, inside and outside their organization, to help vet current
>   common data and any new proposals for addition or amendment of common
>   data. In particular, national standards organizations are encouraged
>   to be involved in the data vetting process.

Probably, not always(all over the world) medium format would look like: `12, Jan 2015`, and decisions are made on country level. If you, as German, have concerns about it - you can try to [fill a ticket with change proposal](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/bug-reports).