# How to display and customize Indian date and time using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys I'm working on my website.

So I wanted to add date and time at seperate place on the page

Indian time is very hard.(php not working with me)

kindly help me with js or provide a php with html embedded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61070560/11061164 The [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is very flexible and can use almost any format of date or time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Date Formatting with IntlDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895154/php-date-formatting-with-intldateformatter)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the default time zone to your Local time zone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");   //India time (GMT+5:30)
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```